# React native searchbar shows flatlist only if first 2 characters are similar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```html
here is my code:import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

const namesData = [
  {fname: 'Sujay', lname: 'Atkare'},
  {fname: 'Pankaj', lname: 'Bhardwaj'},
  {fname: 'Sagar', lname: 'Vande'},
  {fname: 'Rohit', lname: 'Dhanke'},
  {fname: 'Uday', lname: 'Kadam'},
  {fname: 'Abhijeet', lname: 'Shah'},
  {fname: 'Kundan', lname: 'Zalate'},
  {fname: 'Sneha', lname: 'Shinde'},
  {fname: 'Akshay', lname: 'Singh'},
  {fname: 'Dilip', lname: 'Patil'},
  {fname: 'Imran', lname: 'Khan'},
  {fname: 'Saurabh ', lname: 'Kulkarni'},
  
];
const SearchBarScreen = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const _onRenderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  const _searchData = text => {
    if (text) {
      let newList = namesData.filter(item => {
        const newItem = `${(item.fname + '' + item.lname).toUpperCase()}`;
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return newItem.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setData(newList);
      setValue(text);
    } else {
      setData([]);
      setValue(text);
    }
  };

  const _onRenderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 60, borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 1}}
        placeholder="Search here"
        onChangeText={text => _searchData(text)}
        value={value}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        padding: 25,
        width: '98%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Text style={{padding: 10}}>
            {item.fname} {item.lname}
          </Text>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.fname}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => _onRenderSeparator()}
        ListHeaderComponent={_onRenderHeader()}
        enableEmptySections={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SearchBarScreen;
```

I am new to react native,i have been trying to implement a searchbar which recieves list of data from array and render ig using flatlist. But i want to show flatlist only when whose initial characters are similar to the charcters which i type. Ex. If i type in searchbar 'Go'. I want to show list of items starting with 'Go' only

Comment: can you post a code snippet? how far have you achieved?

Comment: here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your specific data format but you would generally want to do something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    // filter your data here. I'm assuming you have a list of strings

    // when user types something and them clears the text, you want to go back to initial list
    if (!query) {
      setData(props.data);
    }

    setData(data.filter((d) => d.includes(query)));
  }, [query]);
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={query}
        onChangeText={(t) => {
          setQuery(t);
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={() => {
          // whatever you want to render
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: i created a searchbar and rendered a flatlist which shows the list of items in it, but suppose i want to search people whose fname starts with S and list should show me only that names which start with S not others having S in between their names, how can i work on that

Comment: you can use the string startsWith method for that `setData(data.filter((d) => d.startsWith(query)));`